# Check if string contains characters other than alphabetical character

Tags: r, boolean-expression

I want a function to return `TRUE` if a string contains only letters, and `FALSE` otherwise.

I had a hard time finding a solution for this problem using R even though there are many answer pages for other languages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `grep`.  We match letters `[A-Za-z]` from the start (`^`) to the end `$` of the string.

```
grepl('^[A-Za-z]+$', str1)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('Azda', 'A123Zda')
```